Find volume of body between surfaces
Problem: Find volume of body defined as follows:
$z^2=xy$, $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{6}}$,   $x, y, z \ge 0$.
My solution:
So we're working in the all positive octant of the Eucledian space.
$0\le z \le \sqrt{xy}$
. Then I did a swap to polar coordinates as follows:
$$x=\sqrt{2}r\cos\theta, y=\sqrt{3}r\sin\theta \\ 0\le r\le \sqrt[6]{\sin\theta\cos\theta} \\ |J|=\sqrt{6}r \\ 0\le z \le r\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
Now I tried the following 2 integrals:
\begin{align}
1)\quad\sqrt{6}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\sqrt[6]{\sin\theta\cos\theta} r\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}\cdot r \ dr \,d\theta = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin\theta\cos\theta \ d\theta= \frac{\sqrt6}{6}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
2)\quad \sqrt{6}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\sqrt[6]{\sin\theta\cos\theta}\int_0^{r\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}} r \ dz \,dr \,d\theta &= \sqrt{6}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}\int_0^\sqrt[6]{\sin\theta\cos\theta} r^2 \,dr \,d\theta\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta  \ d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}
\end{align}
So is my solution correct?

There are some issues:  under the transformation $$x = \sqrt{2} r \cos \theta, \quad y = \sqrt{3} r \sin \theta, \tag{1}$$
your Jacobian is correct, and the limits of integration are correct, but the integrand should instead be
$$z = \sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{\sqrt{6} r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta} = 6^{1/4} r \sqrt{\cos \theta \sin \theta}. \tag{2}$$  Hence
$$\begin{align}
V &= 6^{3/4} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r = 0}^{(\cos \theta \sin \theta)^{1/6}} r^2 \sqrt{\cos \theta \sin \theta} \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= 6^{3/4} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \left[\frac{r^3}{3}\right]_{r = 0}^{(\cos \theta \sin \theta)^{1/6}} (\cos \theta \sin \theta)^{1/2} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{6^{3/4}}{3} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \cos \theta \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{6^{3/4}}{3} \left[\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}\right]_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \\
&= \frac{6^{3/4}}{6} = 6^{-1/4}. 
\end{align}$$

Oh yeah my bad I completely forgot about the double square root of 6. Thank you very much!

@ashamedgap No; $6^{3/4}$ is correct, because you must also include the factor of $\sqrt{6}$ from the Jacobian.
